# Python random.shuffle() producing same result even after I call random.seed()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# N-Queens Problem
import random

# Define size of board
SIZE_OF_BOARD = 8
POPULATION_SIZE = 50

population = []

startingIndividual = []
# Populate starting individual
for x in range(0, SIZE_OF_BOARD):
    startingIndividual.append(x)

for x in range(0, POPULATION_SIZE - 1):
    population.append(startingIndividual)

for x in population:
    random.seed()
    random.shuffle(x)

print(population)
```

So, when I run this program I get the same permutation 50 times. Even though I reseed shuffle for each list I am shuffling, the result is still the same. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: Your `population` list contains 50 references to the *same* list. Replace `population.append(startingIndividual)` with `population.append(startingIndividual[:])`, and remove the `random.seed()` call inside the loop. (Or if you're on Python 3, you might want to write that line as `population.append(startingIndividual.copy())`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson that was it. Such a simple fix, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also note: There is no need to call `seed` more than once (and in other languages, or when passing an explicit seed value in Python, it would *cause* the problem you're trying to avoid).

Comment: @ShadowRanger There is no need to call `seed()` at all.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Agreed, though I understand the impulse to do so, given the problems with not doing so with stuff like C's `rand`.